# posting object to controller mvc2 from silverlight

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, silverlight-4.0, http-post

i have an application on mvc that have a controller with a post method

```
[HttpPost]
public EmptyResult(DispositivoMovil dispositivo)
{
  try
  {
     //Something
  }
}
```

And I have another silverlight application that need to use this method, how can i send a DispositivoMovil object to this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly send an object to this controller from a Silverlight application. You need to send an HTTP POST request by using a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) for example and passing the values in the POST body. Here's an example:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var values = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "PropName1", "value 1" },
    { "PropName2", "value 2" },
    { "ComplexPropName3.SimpleProp", "value 3" },
    // And so on for each value in the DispositivoMovil
};
client.UploadValuesCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    byte[] result = e.Result;
    // TODO: Do something with the response returned from the controller
};
client.UploadValuesAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/home/emptyresult"), values);
```

For more advanced binding scenarios you could take a look at this [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was very useful to me. In silverlight you have to use the class.    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters.Add("Serial", dispositivo.Serial);
            parameters.Add("Observaciones", dispositivo.Observaciones);

Comment: FYI, the UploadValuesAsync() method and UploadValuesCompleted event don't exist in the Silverlight runtime version of WebClient. Instead use UploadStringAsync() and UploadStringCompleted.